# Implications of unified2 logging with multiple instances of snort

Tags: logging, snort

I am beginning to migrate my snort logging from `alert_syslog` to `unified2` using barnyard2 as the processor. In some cases I have multiple instances of snort running on the same system. Since I have historically used syslog, it handled the multiple log input without problem, however with the switch to unified2 I am concerned about write collisions.

Currently, I am using the same `snort.conf` for each instance, and managing the separate instances in `/etc/sysconfig/snort`. Primarily for simplicity of configuration, and partially for development time on my part, I would like to be able to maintain the same `snort.conf`. Which, of course, means having all instances writing to the same unified log file.

I am concerned about write collisions as  multiple processes attempt to write to the same file. Is this a known safe approach with snort? Are the write methods used by the unified2 output processor thread safe? Can anyone comment on the likelihood of total protonic reversal by doing this?